# Where is instruction on how to combine Caliburn.Micro MVVM with Entity Framework in a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, caliburn.micro

**How can I integrate Caliburn.Micro MVVM with Entity Framework for a new WPF 4 application?** I've had no luck so far finding a tutorial. I do not plan to use Silverlight or RIA Services. The application (a CRM for my company) is likely to grow over time. I plan to use PRISM for modularity and hope to combine the three frameworks.

Please note that I will not be using EF Code First. The EDM will be created by dragging tables to the design surface to generate Entities. To benefit from Caliburn.Micro I believe all Entity properties will need to be wrapped to make use of NotifyOfPropertyChange. If so I'd like to find some sort of code generation tool that would make this easier. Perhaps I need to wrap EF in a repository? If you can suggest resources to help me answer these questions it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I've posted a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422912/binding-ef4-with-caliburn-micro-should-i-expose-my-entity-as-a-property-of-the-v).

Comment: I suppose Caliburn.Micro is the MVVM framework dll , as far as I know this should be dealing with the view and viewmodels , NotifyOfPropertyChanged also should be for the viewModels , for modularity I do the following view --> viewModel --> BLL --> DAL , my dal is actually the EF, hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The MVVM pattern doesn't care about the data access method nor does the data access method care about the MVVM pattern.  To get started you can simply write the queries in your ViewModels and then later, refactor them out using a repo pattern.

On the PRISM part and combining the 3 frameworks.  Prism isn't really needed.  Check out the HelloScreens example that comes in the Caliburn Micro source download.  There are 3 subfolders in the client project /Customer /Orders and /Settings.  They're basically modules and could be separated out into separate projects.  [Here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/254102) is a post on that subject.

I love CM but another alternative you might check out is Lightswitch since it's a company CRM.

edit:
Find an example of the repository pattern and EF you like and use that.  Then in your ViewModels and using DI:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : Screen
{
     public IRepository CustomerRepo { get; set; }
     public CustomerViewModel(IRepository customerRepo)
     {
          Customer = customer
     }

     private BindableCollection<Customer> _customers;
     public BindableCollection<Customer> Customers
     {
         get { return _customers; }
         set
         {
             _customers = value;
             NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Customers);
         }
     }

     protected override void OnActivate()
     {
          base.OnActivate();

          Customers = CustomerRepo.GetAll();
        }   
}
```

Comment: You've supplied some good information. However, I'm really hoping to find links to step-by-step instructions or a reference application showing EF and CM combined. I'd like to see context creation & filtering, and how entity properties are wrapped. I'd like to learn if it is possible to simplify development by exposing the entire entity (or ObjectContext) as a property of the ViewModel in a fashion similar to this: http://kboek.blogspot.com/2011/01/activerecord-caliburn-micro-and-one.html

Comment: What do you mean by filtering and wrapping entity properties?

Comment: By filtering I'm looking to return a subset of Customers or just one. By avoiding wrapping properties I mean I don't want to write getters and setters for every database field just to call NotifyOfPropertyChange. I've experimented and found I can avoid writing a million new properties by making just my Entity (model) a property of the ViewModel. But that requires setting the DataContext and all of the binding statements in XAML. Everything I try raises new questions. This is why I'm looking for a detailed tutorial or sample that uses EF4 as the Model or DAL. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/). I was able to write an entire fairly complex app just from that.

Comment: which tutorial sir ?